# Azure DevOps 2019 why Story points are not tracking in our Burndown chart

Tags: azure-devops

With the normal setup of DevOps using agile setting our User stories implement Story points. And only tasks and bugs use effort (aka hours). I am confused why this would be the case. How are we suppose to do any planning if we can not estimate the amount or work need to be done Because User Stories are using Story points and the burn down chart does not recognize this at all. Can I tell the Burn Down chart to measure by story points. Or can I get story points to use effort instead of story points?

I want to be able to measure progress using a burndown chart and I can not seem to get effort as a field in stories or have the burn down chart measure effort.

Answer (score 1):

I've had some early success by adding the Microsoft "Analytics" DevOps Extension. This allows you to track burn down by the sum of story points delivered.

See: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.vss-analytics#overview

Note that at the time of writing this is a free feature "While in Public Preview". May well become chargeable in the future.